# How to write an extension method that allows you to set options without creating the options instance

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, extension-methods

I really like the pattern where I can configure a service through an option class without having to create it, but I can't find an example of how to write an extension method that allows me to use that same pattern such as the one below that exists for registering a DbContext.

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.EnableDetailedErrors());
```

I can see the method signature uses an action method, but I can't seem to find the extension class in GitHub for ASP.NET Core that shows me how to write an extension method using that type of option builder pattern.

For example, take the following service code.  How would I write the extension method so that I could configure the options during service registration.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMyService(options => options.SomeSetting = true);
}

public interface IMyService
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonly MyServiceOptions _options;
    public MyService(IOptions<MyServiceOptions> options)
    {
        _options = options.Value;
    }
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_options.SomeSetting);
    }
}    
public static class MyServiceExtensions
{
    // How would I write this extension method so that I could configure it with options overload
    public static IServiceCollection AddMyService(this IServiceCollection services, Action<MyServiceOptions> configure)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();
        return services;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ASP.NET Core provides this mechanism with the IConfigureOptions
>   interface. You implement this interface in a configuration class and
>   use it to configure the IOptions object in any way you need.

It's as easy as:

```cs
   public class MyServiceConfiguration : IConfigureOptions<MyServiceOptions>
   {
       private MyServiceOptions _options;
       public MyServiceConfiguration(IOptions<MyServiceOptions> options)
       {
           _options = options.Value;
       }

       public void Configure(MyServiceOptions options)
       {
           options.SomeSetting = _options.SomeSetting;
           options.SomeOtherSetting = _options.SomeOtherSetting;
       }
   }
```

> All that remains is to register this implementation in the DI container.:

```cs
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       services.Configure<MyServiceOptions>(options => options.SomeOtherSetting = true);
       services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();
    }
```

With this configuration, when IOptions is injected into your service, the MyServiceOptions object will be configured by the ConfigureMyServiceOptions class.

> `Be careful!` The ConfigureMyServiceOptions object is registered as a singleton,
>   so it will capture any injected services of scoped or transient lifetimes.

Comment: @Geekn Sorry for the errors in the code. I didn't have time to test it out so didn't knew if it compiled. Thanks for the edit. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: I may have not editing it based on what you were indicating because I get a "circular dependency was detected for the service of type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOption" exception when I use the configuration class.  When I don't use the configuration class and just use the Configure(), then it does work but I may be missing something.  In any case, you answer has really helped me!